# can someone explain this tensorflow line of code dataset, metadata = tfds.load('fashion_mnist', as_supervised=True, with_info=True)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm new to Machine Learning. I just enrolled in tensorflow course on Udacity and I'm finding it difficult to understand the following line of code

```
dataset, metadata = tfds.load('fashion_mnist', as_supervised=True, with_info=True)
```

I understand that we are trying to load the fashion_mnist dataset and the following line of code in python would output 5 and 6 respectively when the values of  first and second is printed

```
first, second = 5, 6
```

can someone explain the logic behind the first line of code? it doesn't have two values separated with comma like the second line of code. what are the values of dataset and metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seen on https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/load, when with_info=True, tdfs.load will return a tuple (tf.data.Dataset, tfds.core.DatasetInfo).

```
first, second = (5,6) # for example
```